# How can I prevent VS Code from opening the Open Editors View when revealing in the Explorer a file that is not part of the current workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually have the Open Editors pane toggled off. However I use a keyboard shortcut to "Reveal Active File in Explorer View" quite often while working. This navigates me to the file in my file tree most of the time, but sometimes I'm in a file that doesn't exist in the file tree then the open editors pane pops open like so.

In some random file and I hit the `Reveal Active File in Explorer View` command:
[image: in a screenshot file]

Then I get the Open Editors panel:
[image: open editors pane shown]

This is quite annoying because then I have to close the Open Editors pane manually once again.

Any ideas on how to stop the Open Editors pane from ever showing up?

Comment: Could it be as simple as removing the key binding for "Focus on Open Editors View"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMZxF.png  What is the key bind you have your reveal active file command set to?

Comment: Good idea @TimothyG. but I removed it and am still seeing this issue. It seems like the File: Reveal Active File in Explorer View command will default to opening the open editors view whenever it doesn't find the file in the file tree.

Comment: @starball you're right, I think I was looking at a non-standard diff file. I've updated the example to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

This is just what happens when you reveal in the explorer a file that is not part of the workspace. Unfortunately, I don't know how to prevent it.

But you can at least create a keyboard shortcut that you can mindlessly spam to close it (put this in your keybindings.json file (open that file by running `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.explorer.openEditorsView.toggleVisibility",
    "when": "view.workbench.explorer.openEditorsView.visible"
}
```

A nicer solution would probably look something like being able to write a [when clause](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) for when the current resource is/isn't part of any open workspace folder, and then rebind the `revealInExplorer` command to use that when clause. There might be potential for that to be possible with a when clause for workspace folders gets added (see [#163457](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163457)), but you'd still need to be able to do the string comparison operations, and so far, there's only `=~` for regex matching, which I don't see how you can put a context key inside the `//` delimiters. A custom context key might be needed for when the resource is in one of the workspace folders- something like a "`resourceIsInWorkspaceFolders`" key. You'd need to raise a feature-request for something like that.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.