# How to permanently disable the "Open editors" pane in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

After every restart, VSCode will reopen the "Open editors" pane in the Explorer sidebar.

Comment: use the `...` menu at the top

Comment: @rioV8 as said, it only hides it till the app restart

Comment: it should remember the setting, where did you say it

Comment: what files are open when you restart? if it includes anything outside of the workspace folder, that's why, and this would be a duplicate of the combination of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76344855/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77694676/11107541, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76706419/11107541